# What is the best time or phase of the project to do gulp integration?

Tags: gulp, polymer

I have a frontend project using polymer and so would like to know whether I should do gulp integration before developing several components or after?

Comment: If you need Gulp then use it, otherwise don't . It's not a matter of *when* to use but a matter of *do I need it?*.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Yes, I want to use gulp integration that is why I would like to know the appropriate time to do it during the project development.